# CSS animation "transform: scale" not working in Safari and possibly other browsers

Tags: css, safari

```
@-webkit-keyframes scaleIn {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0);}
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1);}
}

.animate-log-in {
  animation-name: scaleIn;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

It's working on the latest version of Chrome (Mac OSX) but not in the latest version of Safari and an older version (I think) of Chrome. Is there anything I need to add?

Comment: Have you tried using other 'transform' directives in your keyframes, besides the -webkit-transform?

Comment: @ne1410s "translate" works in Safari in another animation I've made, but I haven't tried another "transform"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the below code and try.

```
.animate-log-in {
    -webkit-animation: scaleIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation: scaleIn;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes scaleIn {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    }
}
@keyframes scaleIn {
    from {
        transform: scale(0);
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I noticed another Safari issue when animating scale.

Seems Safari doesn't respects your scale if the element has `display: inline` (e.g. is a span). Make it block or inline-block.

This isn't animation-specific. It also goes for changing the scale with no animation.

This was with Safari 9. Also with the Mobile Safari of iOS 9.

Chrome does not have this issue. It will happily change the scale of an inline element.

JSFiddle to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/ca64gkma/5/

Comment: Bingo! My element was an icon <i>.
I just added "display: block" to the animation class and it works now.
Gladly, changing the display value does not affect anything else.

Answer (score -1):

instead of `scale` try `zoom`, for webkits values ranging from 100% as scale 1 , 1.5 = 150% and so on